# What does <exp+6> mean in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I was debugging a C++ code using gdb. The program stopped due to a segmentation fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

So I was trying to print out the value of variables to identify where the error is coming from. I have an array called 'ring' of type 'Link **', where Link is a class I defined. Each element in the array points to a 'Link *' variable. Here is the output when I print the first three elements of the 'ring' array.

```
(gdb) print ring[0]
$13 = (Link *) 0x8125290
(gdb) print ring[1]
$14 = (Link *) 0xb7e80b86 <exp+6>
(gdb) print ring[2]
$15 = (Link *) 0x8132e20
```

Why am I getting '' after the memory address when printing 'ring[1]'? What does it mean?

EDIT: Im using gdb 7.8 on Arch Linux (3.16.4-1-ARCH)

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I could have got the wrong end of the stick, but is that a corrupted pointer that happens to point into the code segment (the address of the `exp` function plus 6 bytes)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Im using Arch Linux (3.16.4-1)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use also [valgrind](http://valgrind/) in addition of `gdb`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the pointer value is equal to the address of the `exp` symbol plus 6.  It's just the debugger trying to be helpful—whenever it decodes any pointer value, it tries to see if the pointer happens to lie near any known symbols in the object code, and it prints out that information if so.

You might expect to see such notation when examining the disassembly of a function's code, e.g. in branch targets, but as a data pointer, that's very unusual (function pointers would tend to point directly at function symbols, not offset into them).

You almost certainly have some kind of memory corruption bug that just happens to produce that value as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks. As you rightly assessed, there was a memory bug.